# Android: Progress bar that shows a countdown?

Tags: android, progress-bar, handler

I a currently using a new thread to create a UI thread and then displaying a progress bar. Can someone tell me how to do the same for a thirty second progress dialog (should do some work and disappear after this duration) that can be done using a handler instead?